# Listing database values via a List in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to show database values assigned to a List in C# but am running into an issue when trying to show them. Instead of what I want it to show, it shows this: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Here is my code:

```
public List<string>[] selectQuery(string query)
    {
        // create a list to hold the firt name, last name, and password
        List<string>[] list = new List<string>[4];

        list[0] = new List<string>(); // will hold the first name
        list[1] = new List<string>(); // will hold the last name
        list[2] = new List<string>(); // will hold the username
        list[3] = new List<string>(); // will hold the password

        if (this.openDbConnection() == true)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, this.connection);

            MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            // read the data and store it in the list
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                list[0].Add(dr["first_name"] + "");
                list[1].Add(dr["last_name"] + "");
                list[2].Add(dr["username"] + "");
                list[3].Add(dr["password"] + "");
            }

            // close reading the data operator
            dr.Close();

            // close connection
            this.connection.Close();

            // return the list of results to be displayed
            return list;
        }
        else
        {
            return list;
        }
    }


  List<string>[] data = db.selectQuery("SELECT first_name, last_name, username, password FROM member WHERE username = '" + name + "'" + " AND password = PASSWORD('" + pass + "')");

        if (data != null)
        {
            // assign the username, password, first and last name to the  session variables
            Session["first_name"] = data[0].ToString();
            Session["last_name"]  = data[1].ToString();
            Session["username"]   = data[2].ToString();
            Session["password"]   = data[3].ToString();


            // redirect to member page
            Response.Redirect("members.aspx", false);
        }
```

and the html is:

```
    <tr>
        <td id="user"><%=Session["username"].ToString()%></td>
        <td id="greeting"><%=Session["first_name"].ToString()%></td>
    </tr>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: your making an array of `List<string>`   so first you need to identify it's position in the Array   `data[0]`   then you need to identify the location of the string in the `List<string>` by doing something like `data[0][0]`   i've never tried that so i have no idea if it will actually work.  But currently your trying to turn a `List<string>` object into a string, hence the message your getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so much more complex then it needs to be.  Create an object:

```
public class User
{
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public User()
    {
    }
}
```

then in your code:

```
public User selectQuery(string query)
{
    User myuser = new User();

    //use this if you want to create a List of users and change the method type to "List<User>" and the return to userList.
    List<User> userList = new List<User> ();

    if (this.openDbConnection() == true)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, this.connection);

        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        // read the data and store it in the list
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            myuser.first_name = dr["first_name"] + "";
            myuser.last_name= dr["last_name"] + "");
            myuser.username = dr["username"] + "");
            myuser.password = dr["password"] + "");

            //use the below line only if you are expecting to return multiple users
            userList.Add(myuser);
        }

        // close reading the data operator
        dr.Close();

        // close connection
        this.connection.Close();

        // return the list of results to be displayed
        return myuser;
    }
    else
    {
        return myuser;
    }
}
```

finally you just call the method then access the properties of the returned value

```
User myuser = db.selectQuery("blah");

        if (data != null)
    {
        // assign the username, password, first and last name to the  session variables
        Session["first_name"] = myuser.first_name.ToString();
        Session["last_name"]  = myuser.last_name.ToString();
        Session["username"]   = myuser.username.ToString();
        Session["password"]   = myuser.password.ToString();
    }
```

etc  or if your returning a list do the following

```
List<User> myusers = db.selectQuery("blah")

if(!myusers.Count == 1)  //this will let you check if it returns multiple users for some reason
{
        Session["first_name"] = myusers[0].first_name.ToString();
        Session["last_name"]  = myusers[0].last_name.ToString();
        Session["username"]   = myusers[0].username.ToString();
        Session["password"]   = myusers[0].password.ToString();
}
```